# Pandas: Counting frequencies of values delimited by ";" in a column

Tags: pandas

I have Google form data, in which one column as multiple options data. Now I need to make a pie chart of the column by counting specific strings in the same column. My data looks like this

```
"Option A; option B"
"Option A; option B, option C,"
"Option A; option C"
"Option A; option C"
```

I need to show it in a pie chart stating the following values Option A: count = 4, Option B: count = 2, Option C: count = 3.

I tried breaking up the columns but need to do it in a more systematic way.

Comment: Can you be more explicit on the real dataset? You mix ;/, and change the case. Please provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one separator `;` use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = df['col'].str.split(r';\s*').explode().value_counts()
```

If there is multiple separators, `,` and `;` like in sample data use:

```
s = df['col'].str.strip(',;').str.split(r'[,;]\s*').explode().value_counts()
```

Last plot by [`Series.plot.pie`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.pie.html):

```
s.plot.pie()
```

EDIT: For 2 graphs per `type`s use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
print (df)
                             col  Test-type
0             Option A; option B   pre-test
1  Option A; option B, option C,   pre-test
2             Option A; option C  post-test
3             Option A; option C  post-test

df = df.assign(col = df['col'].str.strip(',;').str.split(r'[,;]\s*')).explode('col')

df1 = pd.crosstab(df['col'], df['Test-type'])
print (df1)
Test-type  post-test  pre-test
col                           
Option A           2         2
option B           0         2
option C           2         1

df1.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(8, 3))
```

Comment: I had the same in mind but this won't work if the data is faithful

Comment: @mozway - yop, agree, so added solution for data in question

Comment: This works well. There is a twist in my data. I have to make two charts based on values from pre-test and post-test forms. These values are written in a separate column named as "Test-type"

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, I was using crosstabs before splitting. Trying this new method.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which is based on `list comprehension`:

```
l = [x.str.split('; |,\s*').tolist()[0] for _, x in df.iterrows()]
a = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist if item != '']
pd.Series(a).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Option A    4
option C    3
option B    2
Name: count, dtype: int64
```